# Using Static vs Passing Parameters

Tags: java, object-oriented, state

I'm implementing a state-pattern design in Java to calculate the current position of an object following a trapezoidal trajectory.

The pattern consists of a Context, State and states classes.

Currently, the variables (accel, max_vel and target) are passed as parameters to each state object upon instantiation - in effect, the variables "trickle" down to each state regardless of wether they are used or not.

It occurred to me that I could just create three protected (as the states are private classes) static variables which hold the values. This way each object doesn't need to store unnecessary variables.

Can anyone see a problem with this?

Comment: Are accel, max_vel and target constants? Will there be different instances of your object with different values for them?

Comment: No, they are not constant. They are passed as parameters to the Context object.

Comment: Ok. Maybe a better question is this: do you expect accel, etc. to be shared across all instances of your objects (which is what using a static member will accomplish)?

Comment: I see what you mean, but there will only ever be one instance of the objects running at once.

Answer (score 4):

You should keep them as parameters.

I can't see any benefit to making them static, performance or otherwise.  For example, parameters are usually passed in cpu registers, whereas statics live in  memory.

On the downside, using statics will make your code more fragile to future changes, including, creating a second such object, and also using multiple threads.  Statics make testing more difficult, re: mocking.

The intent of the code will also be clearer with parameters than with statics.

So, with only downside, let's use parameters as they're meant to be used, and let's avoid statics for passing parameter information to objects.

---

On the other hand, it seems that your configuration should be extracted into its own class, and this one configuration object then shared with the state classes (as a single object instead of multiple parameters).

Answer (score 3):

Your question is tagged as object-oriented related so I think it's important to be clear that using static values in this way is completely at odds with object orientation.  It's also a *really bad idea*™ in general.  What you are describing is basically the same using global variables for message passing.

Based on what you have described, it sounds like these properties should be member level variables or just method parameters.  The cost of these 'extra variables' is so insignificant, it shouldn't be considered.  The compiler or JIT might even eliminate them.

Unless you are building a throw-away application, using static variables in the this way is definitely going to be a problem in the long run.

Comment: the cost of the 'extra variables' may be insignificant, but isn't it bad design practice for an object to be holding values which it isn't actually using itself?

Comment: It's not optimal but definitely preferable to using statics.  By using statics in that way you will make your application extremely difficult to extend.  Whether that ends up being an issue will depend on whether you ever need to extend it.  With no other information other than personal experience, I would assume you will.  The cost is so low to do it right, you will win out if you only extend 1 out of 10 (or more) applications you write.  Consider using DI or even a Singleton (the former is generally preferred.)

Comment: Don't know much about DI. Could you perhaps briefly explain how I would apply it to this application and why it would be useful? Ta

Comment: Is this what Erik was suggesting in the ending to his question above?

Comment: @MartinRand I believe so, yes.